# Error in docker-compose build. version issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i have docker-compose installed with version 1.13

```
 docker-compose --version
 docker-compose version 1.13.0, build 1719ceb
```

but when i run docker-compose build it says

> ERROR: The Docker Engine version is less than the minimum required by
>   Compose. Your current project requires a Docker Engine of version
>   1.13.0 or greater.

i have tried to upgrade it to version 1.14 using 
https://github.com/docker/compose/releases

but i gives same response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Docker engine are you using? You need to upgrade Docker engine version as Docker compose format needs later version of Docker engine.